# Пустой массив $_GET

Tags: php

Передаю get параметры, но при получении сталкиваюсь с проблемой - $_GET пустой, var_dump показывает NULL, ума не приложу как так получается. При том, что на локальном сервере всё нормально, на другом хостинге тоже всё работает в штатном режиме.
Как заставить передать GET параметры?
[image: Скриншот ошибки]

[image: Сервер]

Comment: Какой веб-сервер и его конфиг?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Не вижу конфиг nginx

Comment: @Александр может вместо $_GET нужно смотреть QUERY_STRING ? `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `var_dump($_GET)`.
Возможно у вас до этого где-то во фреймворке или другим разрабом написан разбор `URL-а` и создание оберток для кастомных параметров.
Если там ничего нет, то проверьте `track_vars`. (в `phpinfo();` есть инфа). Если отключено - включите в `php.ini`
Проверьте, не менялось ли `--enable-track-vars`